# Networkrequest Result wrapper with caching

Tags: android, mvvm

There are a load of samples in Android where a network request in the repository is performed and the result is Returned in a Result wrapper.

```
sealed class Resource<T> {
    class Success<T>(val data: T) : Resource<T>()
    class Error<T>(val error: Throwable? = null) : Resource<T>()
}
```

and in the repository something like this is called

```
suspend fun getUsers(): Resource<List<User>> {   
    return try {
        //response is List<User>
        val response = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { service.getAllUsers() }
        Resource.Success(response)
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
        Timber.d(e.message)
        Resource.Failure()
    }
}
```

this is result is then handles in the viewmodel. However i was not able to find any examples that use this approach in combination with caching the result in for example a room database.

When directly caching the result and and returning the current users from the database I dont see how i effectively should handle for example a network error, still return users from the database if any are cached and make the viewmodel recognize that something was not working as intended.

Should i seperate the store logic from the fetch logic. This means: fetch data and return it to the viewmodel. and the viewmodel then calls the repostiroy again to store the fetched data and get the current state of the database. Should i generally drop the Resource result wrapper. When is a result wrapper required and when is it a bad practice.

Comment: Would you want to cache an error response?  Generally an error means you don't have data and want to try again later

Comment: @GabeSechan  i do not want to cache an error response. but on error i still want to display the cached data. If the phone is in flight mode for example. The request will fail but i can still show cached data.

Comment: Ok, that's a fairly normal pattern.  Generally you have an access layer, say UserRepository with a function fetchAll() that first attempts to hit the network.  If it fails it reads from the DB, if it succeeds it updates the DB.  Or another pattern is to have it always read from the DB, but run the network action in the background to update the data (generally combined with a flow  to update when finished).  The main thing is you create a layer that's responsible for fetching from the right source, and then your viewmodel calls that function, and it never calls the network or db directly.

Comment: @GabeSechan the main intent of my question is regardin the case if it fails it read from the DB. in this case how would I return the fetched data AND notify the viewmodel that something failed. Is the Resource  Wrapper suitable for this. or should i always seperate fetching from network and database.